# How to get all elements in a selection from javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using `window.getSelection()` to get the highlighted selection in a `contenteditable` div. I can get the range of nodes with `selection.getRangeAt(0)`. But now I'm stuck. How can I get the node/elements to do something with them, like add a class to each element in the range?

I can do something like this, `range.cloneContents().querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e => console.log(e));` to see what the would be but they are cloned, so doing anything with the elements does *nothing* in the actual document.

So, I've got my selection, but how to I get a list of nodes/elements in the selection?